# Swift - UIViews order programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have several UIView layers in one ViewController. 
[image: Several UIViews layers]

How can I determine the order of UIView programmatically?

Comment: What kind of data do you want as "order"?  IOW, if you had a function that answered your question what data type would it return?

Comment: I need to manipulate UIView order in ViewController, change the z index or stack order of a UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are ordered from back-most to front-most in `view.subviews` array.

---

For example, here are 3 subview added to an empty view.

```
view.addSubview(UILabel())
view.addSubview(UIButton())
view.addSubview(UITextField())
```

Printing the subviews with the following code

```
for view in view.subviews {
    print(view.debugDescription)
}
```

has the output

```
<UILabel: 0x7feef00042e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60400008c210>>
<UIButton: 0x7feef00045c0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000222300>>
<UITextField: 0x7feeef02c800; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = ''; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60800005b090>; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000222280>>
```

---

When the views are reordered, the position in `view.subviews` changes

```
if let button = view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIButton }) {
    view.bringSubview(toFront: button)
}
```

Now, printing the view, has the output

```
<UILabel: 0x7feef00042e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60400008c210>>
<UITextField: 0x7feeef02c800; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = ''; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60800005b090>; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000222280>>
<UIButton: 0x7feef00045c0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000222300>>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution...

In the UIView documentation, where are several methods listed for the manipulation of the order of subviews:

```
bringSubviewToFront(_:)

sendSubviewToBack(_:)

removeFromSuperview()

insertSubview(_:atIndex:)

insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)

insertSubview(_:belowSubview:)

exchangeSubviewAtIndex(_:withSubviewAtIndex:)
```

In Swift 4.0

```
view.sendSubview(toBack:yourUIView)

view.bringSubview(toFront:yourUIView)
```

Comment: This answer and your question don't make sense. Your question is 'how do I find out the order', but your answer is 'how do I change the order'.

Comment: My question is: How can I determine the order of UIView programmatically? "Determine" in this case means how can i make UIView1 - 1st,  UIView2 -2nd, an so on, programmatically.

Comment: You want to do this in storyboard or progrmaticcaly

Comment: I can do this in storyboard easily manually, the subject about how implement it programmatically.